# AppBarLayout and RecyclerView not siblings

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I have a toolbar which I would like to behaves as material design specifications. In this way, I wrapped it in a `AppBarLayout`. The problem is that the `RecyclerView` is a child of a `ViewPager`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <com.rocket.android.views.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/pager_indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/tab_and_nav_bar"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I attach the `AppBarLayout` to react to an arbitrary `RecyclerView` which is not his sibling?

Comment: Check out chris banes' cheesesquare project on github he does exactly what you want: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare I think you need to use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: However, I still have a small bug. The view pager has 4 pages. 2 of them are not scrollable, since they contains few elements. For those pages, the bottom edge of the layouts are cut off the screen by the same height as the toolbar. Do you may know why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. these things are brand new. Maybe if you posted a screenshot + xml it could help.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with some views hosted in my fragment pager gets cut off at the bottom, just wondering if you've managed to solve it? The only good solution I can see is to subclass and override onMeasure of the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. Possible (but worse) solution is to dynamically add bottom padding to ViewPager

Comment: @MaxCh sorry my late reply. You can see how I solved it below. Not the cleanest solution I know, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/d2"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tab_and_nav_bar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This brings a padding-related problem for the pages in the `ViewPager`. I solved this one adding a padding which size is the same height of the tab layout. It works. Not the best solution though.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate? the xml above doesn't explain how your paddings are set

Comment: The hidden part of the layouts inside the pager depend on the height if the toolbar. Adding the same space as padding at the bottom of each layout will clearly solve the problem. The paddings are set on each layout of the pager.